# Exporting data through RODBC in Excel

Tags: r, export-to-excel, rodbc

After performing calculations in R we wanto to export the results in an Excel file in order to make some formatting and to add graphs. I fould the following page

http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/10/06/export-data-frames-to-multi-worksheet-excel-file/

which reports the following code

```
> library(RODBC) 

> save2excel <- function(x) sqlSave(xlsFile,
     x, tablename = x$Species[1], rownames = FALSE)    

> xlsFile <- odbcConnectExcel("RODBC.xls", readOnly = FALSE)
> l_ply(testlist, save2excel)
> odbcCloseAll()
```

I have some difficulties in implementing it in fact it returns an error like:

```
Errore in sqlSave(xlsFile, x, tablename = NULL, rownames = FALSE) : 
  should be a data frame
```

Do you have any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It looks like x is a list/vector.You can only save data frames as excel sheets. If you provide more info on your data structure, we could help you.

A most general approach, if your data in the list/vector form, it can be a prob, but if it is a logical table( matrix/data table etc) you can do an `as.data.frame(x)` to make it a DF.

Comment: Having a data.frame this code does not return any error in R but in opening the xls file created we cannot open it since an Excel box says it is corrupted... Why that happened?

Answer (score 0):

I used the same (great) blog post and ran into both of the same errors (data frame and excel file corrupted). Sounds like you got the data.frame part figured out but are still getting the corrupt file error. I had to remove the function aspect of the bloggers post to get rid of that error.

```
newdat <- data.frame(rnorm(100,0,10))

xlsFile <- odbcConnectExcel("Test.xls", readOnly = FALSE)
sqlSave(xlsFile,newdat, append=FALSE)
odbcCloseAll()
```

This should create a new worksheet, called "newdat" in the file called "Test.xls". If that file already exists, it will be a new worksheet. Otherwise it will create the file and be the only worksheet.